# How do you play this section from “La Campanella”?

Tags: sheet-music, violin

So I decided to learn La Campanella 3rd movement violin just for the heck of it and I got to this part: 
[image: violin section]
You’re supposed to play ninths with your 2nd and 4th fingers. How is this even possible? It’s hard enough to play ninths with 1st and 4th fingers. Do people really play this? Any advice on how to tackle this? Should I go into higher positions? Should I just keep practicing doing an ultra stretch? Anyone had to deal with this? Thanks

Comment: How big are your hands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's high(ish), it can be stretched in an extended 3rd position.  I could manage it and I don't have big hands.  The only thing I would question is the 2 on the C.  Since you already have 2 on the Eb (before and after the C), I would put 3 on the C.

Comment: I figured it out! I basically have to turn my hand parallel to the fingerboard to reach it. Also, I personally think that the 2 on the C helps you put your arm in the correct orientation to reach it. Otherwise it’s difficult to rotate your hand. I definitely think my hands are on the smaller side, but I realized that by rotating my hand I can reach much further. I think the issue most people like me have is they approach every stretch the wrong way...maybe...but wow I can almost reach 2 octaves in first position now